# Retrieve next page data through Alamofire request using RxSwift

Tags: pagination, alamofire, rx-swift

I have some existing code that fetches messages from the server. The server is in Django and returns paginated data. Hence, the first call that goes to the server fetches the 10 latest results, the next call should bring more results and so on...

However, the problem is that only the first request is being send to the server. So it only loads the 10 latest results and nothing else. I want to modify the code such that app is able to fetch all results.

**JSON Response**

**Request: http://192.168.0.127:8000/v1/topic/1/message/**

```
{
  "count": 12,
  "next": "http://192.168.0.127:8000/v1/topic/1/message/?page=2",
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 12,
      "topic": 1,
      "photo_url": "",
      "message": "Test12",
      "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "John",
        "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/437334666655912/picture/?type=large",
        "last_seen_event": null,
        "blocked": false
      },
      "created_on": "2017-05-22T07:50:42.335694Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "topic": 1,
      "photo_url": "",
      "message": "Test11",
      "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "John",
        "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/437334666655912/picture/?type=large",
        "last_seen_event": null,
        "blocked": false
      },
      "created_on": "2017-05-22T07:50:13.931648Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "topic": 1,
      "photo_url": "",
      "message": "Test10",
      "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "John",
        "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/437334666655912/picture/?type=large",
        "last_seen_event": null,
        "blocked": false
      },
      "created_on": "2017-05-22T07:50:07.819994Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "topic": 1,
      "photo_url": "",
      "message": "Test9",
      "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "John",
        "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/437334666655912/picture/?type=large",
        "last_seen_event": null,
        "blocked": false
      },
      "created_on": "2017-05-22T07:49:59.896686Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "topic": 1,
      "photo_url": "",
      "message": "Test8",
      "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "John",
        "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/437334666655912/picture/?type=large",
        "last_seen_event": null,
        "blocked": false
      },
      "created_on": "2017-05-22T07:48:47.268219Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "topic": 1,
      "photo_url": "",
      "message": "Test7",
      "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "John",
        "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/437334666655912/picture/?type=large",
        "last_seen_event": null,
        "blocked": false
      },
      "created_on": "2017-05-22T07:48:36.587173Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "topic": 1,
      "photo_url": "",
      "message": "Test6",
      "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "John",
        "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/437334666655912/picture/?type=large",
        "last_seen_event": null,
        "blocked": false
      },
      "created_on": "2017-05-22T07:48:29.111922Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "topic": 1,
      "photo_url": "",
      "message": "Test5",
      "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "John",
        "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/437334666655912/picture/?type=large",
        "last_seen_event": null,
        "blocked": false
      },
      "created_on": "2017-05-22T07:48:22.983123Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "topic": 1,
      "photo_url": "",
      "message": "Test4",
      "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "John",
        "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/437334666655912/picture/?type=large",
        "last_seen_event": null,
        "blocked": false
      },
      "created_on": "2017-05-22T07:48:12.986871Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "topic": 1,
      "photo_url": "",
      "message": "Test3",
      "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "John",
        "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/437334666655912/picture/?type=large",
        "last_seen_event": null,
        "blocked": false
      },
      "created_on": "2017-05-22T07:48:05.376769Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Request: http://192.168.0.127:8000/v1/topic/1/message/?page=2**

```
{
  "count": 12,
  "next": null,
  "previous": "http://192.168.0.127:8000/v1/topic/1/message/",
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "topic": 1,
      "photo_url": "",
      "message": "Test2",
      "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "John",
        "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/437334666655912/picture/?type=large",
        "last_seen_event": null,
        "blocked": false
      },
      "created_on": "2017-05-22T07:47:59.367765Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "topic": 1,
      "photo_url": "",
      "message": "Test1",
      "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "John",
        "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/437334666655912/picture/?type=large",
        "last_seen_event": null,
        "blocked": false
      },
      "created_on": "2017-05-22T07:47:49.372195Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Code**

```
fileprivate lazy var _getMessagesAction: Action<EnumerableType, EnumerableType> = Action { (last: EnumerableType?) -> Observable<EnumerableType> in

        self.isNewRequest = last?.next == nil ? true : false

        return self.messagesRequest(last)
}
```

The `last` variable is always nil right now.

`typealias EnumerableType = Enumerable<Message>`

Here is the **Enumerable** class

```
public struct Enumerable<EnumerableType: ResponseCollectionModelSerializable> : ResponseModelSerializable {

    let count: Int
    let prev: String?
    let next: String?
    let results: [EnumerableType]?

    public init?(response: HTTPURLResponse, json: JSON) {
        guard let countOBj = json["count"] else {
            return nil
        }

        self.count = countOBj as! Int
        self.prev = json["previous"] as? String
        self.next = json["next"] as? String

        if let results = json["results"] as? AnyObject {
            self.results = EnumerableType.collection(response: response, json: JSON(results))
        } else {
            self.results = nil
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I don't feel like you posted enough to create a specific example for your situation, but there is sample code for doing this sort of thing.

In the RxSwift GitHub repo, there are several examples including GitHubSearchRepositories which loads data in pages.

I also wrote this gist: https://gist.github.com/danielt1263/10bc5eb821c752ad45f281c6f4e3034b which includes tests and details a view model for a view controller complete with an Observable for displaying an activity indicator.

Comment: I have updated the gist for Swift 4.2, and improved it.

Comment: nice gist that can be plugged anywhere, however, I have tried it and I got two concerns: (1) I guess checking the page against -1 in the line Observable.combineLatest(Observable.just(page), loadData(page == -1 ? 1 : page)) is redundant because the page never be -1 at this point ?     (2) once I subscribe to the PaginationSink.elements observable it emits empty array [] as a 'next' event before even listening to the 'refresh' trigger, why is that happening ?

Comment: (1) It's not redundant because the page can be -1 at that point (if the user wants to refresh.) (2) As shown in the test harness, upon creation the code will immediately attempt to load the first page. Why your first page is an empty array is something for you to figure out. Check out the test harness that comes with the code for information on how it works.

Comment: I have transferred my concerns regarding this gist into the comments sections of its page.